# is entropy the same up to a constant?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

I have understood that what's important about entropy is its change $\Delta S$, not $S$ itself, much like the electrostatic potential. Therefore, can I assume that a constant entropy can be redefined to be zero?

In particular, I have, for high temperatures, $S=2+\Sigma n_{i}ln(n_{i})$, Can I say that $S=\Sigma n_{i}ln(n_{i})$ ?

Comment: One of the versions of the third law of thermodynamics states that the entropy must go to zero at zero temperature, which sets an overall scale.

Answer (score 2):

No. Entropy is essentially the count of accessible microstates for the system. You can't arbitrarily change this number. Of course mathematically you can do this if you are only interested in changes in entropy. But you shouldn't interpret this as "moving the entropy scale".

---

Small aside: you ask if we can do this when entropy is constant, but I'm unsure why you ask about this condition. You bring up the potential energy analogy. With potential energy we don't wait for the potential energy to be constant and then set that potential energy to $0$. We set the scale first (where the zero point is in space) and then determine potential energy values from there, constant or not. For entropy the scale is just set by the definition, and I suppose the [third law of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_law_of_thermodynamics)

Answer (score -1):

The point is that if the change of the entropy has a constant, you can ignore it, like the constant value "2" in the equation you posted.